# What does the red silo icon mean in Eclipse Subversive?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, subversive

I am using subversive with Eclipse Keppler. I am very familiar with the yellow silo icon. But now in some projects I also have a red silo icon :

[image]

What does it mean?

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/preferences/pref_label_decors.php

Comment: so this means that there is a conflict that exists somewhere under this directory?